# How to get data from POST/GET method in a C program?

Tags: c, http

I want to write a simple program that takes data from forms via POST OR GET. A simple form lets say for adding two numbers.

I saw that libcurl is capable of talking with http protocol but I did not see any example related to this question.

All i saw is how to send data to webpage but not how to get it.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: For [CGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Gateway_Interface), I believe GET is part of the URL, POST is received through `stdin`

Comment: Yes, POST is read from stdin and GET is part of the URL, but the CGI does not see the URL, the CGI gets access to the environment variable QUERY_STRING.

Comment: Also, please note that curl is intended as a web client, libcurl is probably not very usable to write a CGI program in C. To read the GET data you will instead need to use getenv() and to read POST data you will need to read from stdin with your favorite function call to do that.

Comment: Thank you! I think i found what i was looking for! https://jkorpela.fi/forms/cgic.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick-n-dirty, ***very untested*** example based on another project of mine - no warranties express or implied.  This assumes that the binary has properly been deployed on the Web server (for example, under the `cgi-bin` directory on an Apache server) and that the input form has been set up to call it properly:

```
<form action="http://my-url.com/cgi-bin/adder" method="get"> <!-- or method="post" -->
  <label for="v1">V1:</label><input type="text" name="v1"><br>
  <label for="v2">V2:</label><input type="text" name="v2"><br>
  <input type="submit" name="submitbutton" value="Add">
</form>
```

Then your C code will look something like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char **argv )
{
  char *interface = getenv( "GATEWAY_INTERFACE" );

  /**
   * If interface is NULL, then we were not invoked through CGI.  
   * For this example we just fail silently.
   */
  if ( !interface )
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );

  char *method = getenv( "REQUEST_METHOD" );

  /**
   * If method is NULL, then we were not invoked through CGI;
   * for this example we'll just fail silently
   */
  if ( !method )
   exit( EXIT_FAILURE );

  if ( strcmp( method, "GET" ) == 0 )
  {
    /**
     * We were invoked from a Web client with the HTTP GET method - 
     * input parameters will be in the QUERY_STRING environment
     * variable as "param=value&param=value"
     */
    char *query_string = getenv( "QUERY_STRING" );
    do_stuff_with( query_string );
  }
  else if ( strcmp( method, "POST" ) == 0 )
  {
    /**
     * We were invoked from a Web client with the HTTP POST method - 
     * input parameters will be received via standard input
     */
    char query_string[SOME_SIZE];
    if ( fgets( query_string, sizeof query_string, stdin ) )
    {
      do_stuff_with( query_string );
    }
    else
      // handle error
  }
  else
  {
    /**
     * Input method is not GET or POST, log an error and fail
     */ 
    fputs( "Don't know how to handle this request\n", stderr );
    exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
  }
}
```

Any response back to the Web client will be written through standard output:

```
printf( "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n" );
printf( "<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><head><title>Adder result</title></head>" );
printf( "<body><p>Result of add is %d</p></body></html>", add_result );
```